# if you know you have 2 database items and 5 per page. If the user requests a page, how do you know if that page exisits or not?

Tags: php

if you know you have 2 database items and your pagination does 5 per page. If the user requests a page, how do you know if that page exisits or not? I'm trying to make it if someone requests a page and that page doesn't have items on it, default to page 1. So like if i requested page 2, it should default to page 1. I was thinking it would be some math but not really sure.

Comment: are you putting links on your site to pages that shouldn't exist?

Comment: No... But like if i go to page 2, no items show up. So i want to make it default to page 1 if that page number doesn't exist.

Comment: unless you redirect using headers, this practice may screw up bookmarking, link sharing, and search engine indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$requestedPage = (int)$_GET['page'];

if ( ceil( $numResults / $perPage ) < $requestedPage ) { 
  $requestedPage = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you cannot prevent user from entering out-of-range values manually.
So, being you, I would just don't care.

Just show him a blank page

Comment: That would make fabulous user experience. Fantastic advice.

Answer (score 0):

When you query data for second page, if result is empty that go to first page.

Answer (score 0):

With each request you divide the count() of rows by the number per page and round it up to the nearest whole number.

This will give you the total number of pages. Before each request you check that the request page is <= to last page.

Heres some helpful functions you can use as an example:

```
        private function countRecords() {
            $this->recordCount = count($this->data);
            return;
    }

    private function calcPages() {
            $this->totalPages = ceil( $this->recordCount / $this->perPage );
            return;
    }

    private function checkCurrent() {
            $this->currentPage = ($this->currentPage > $this->totalPages ?
                                            $this->totalPages :
                                            $this->currentPage);
            $this->currentPage = ($this->currentPage < 1 ? 1 : $this->currentPage);
            return;
    }

    private function calcOffset() {
            $this->offset = ($this->currentPage - 1) * $this->perPage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation would be simply to check whether the database returns any rows. You didn't mention your database server or your framework's interface, so I can't give you any real code, but coarsely:

```
if(num_rows($query) == 0 && $page != 1) {
  redirect_to_page_one() && return;
}
```

You can of course do it transparently instead of doing a redirect, but that starts to get somewhat hard to follow.